# Can VisualStudio Code be used to debug C++ programs?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

I am looking for a cross OS compatible IDE which supports IntelliSense (checking availability of functions & argument docs) and debugging for C and C++ (Supports watch and breakpoints)

Comment: It really depends on what typoe of *intellisense* you want. Is it code completion, checking function arguments, checking availability of functions or annoying features like forcing you to use function names that do exist instead of the ones you have yet to write and you have to go back to re-edit the name.

Comment: I [edited your question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38045930/3) to hopefully clarify it, as it almost sounded like a tool recommendation which would be off-topic. If you feel I have changed the meaning or removed essential information, you can [edit] your own question or roll back my edit.

Comment: That being said, the [tag for VSCode](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vscode/info) may answer your question

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
VSCode – C/C++ extension is to provide cross-platform C++ developers a great tool of choice for their edit-build-debug cycle with the same consistent look and feel across all platforms.